# Keyboard won't dismiss on iPhone search

Tags: html, ios, css, angularjs, keyboard

I just implemented a search bar on my website and I'm getting a strange bug: when you push the search button on your iPhone, the keyboard doesn't dismiss - but the search works! In other words, if you click on the textbox, type in what you're searching for, then push the "Search" button on your iPhone keyboard, the search results appear, but the keyboard is still in the way. Clearly the form submitted, but iOS doesn't seem to leet you see the result.

Here's my code:

```
<form style="margin-bottom: 20px; text-align: center" class="visible-xs" ng-submit="updateEvents()">
  <div>
    <input type="text" id="textSearch" class="form-control" ng-model="search_text" placeholder="Search Here" style="margin-bottom: 5px">
  </div>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">
    <i class="fa fa-search"></i> Search
  </button>
</form>
```

You can also see the site live at [SparkMyInterest.com](http://sparkmyinterest.com)

ALSO: Just a note, I am using angular in this app.

Answer (score 0):

According to my iOS programming book you need to resign the first responder:

```
[textField resignFirstResponder];
```

I'm guessing that you'd call this from a method like textFieldDidEndEditing.   Or wherever you start the search from.

Comment: haha yea that's how you do it in objective-c, but I was asking in css/ html. thank you though

Comment: Sorry, can't help with that.